# Find items not in datatable that are present in List<customclass>

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

I have tried to find they way to get a list of objects by crossing the common fields between a IEnumerable Datarow and a custom Class.

I load a dataset and using DataSetExtensions assembly I turn it to a IEnumerable Datarow()

```
  Dim listaRows = ds.Tables(0).AsEnumerable().Cast(Of DataRow).ToList()
```

Then I have a List of custom class loaded with objects I can use to cross the datarow fields.

Basically, the custom Class has a proeprty called `ParsedFileName`and this items is present
in the datarows with property name `Filename`.

I need to find out the way of creating a linq query that finds with elements (based on filename field) are present in the List that are not present in the Ienumerable Datarow.

I can not use `List<T>.Except` because it receives an argument that is a second Ienumerable collection of the same class.

I was trying to think about how could the query be but I only managed to get something like this, and It is not valid because it uses equals not except.

I was trying something like this:

```
 Dim list As List(Of sftpClass.SftpObj) = _
                listaFichero.Select(Function(l) Not l.FicheroParsed. _
                            Equals(listaRows.Select(Function(r) _
                                                        r.Field(Of String)("FICHERO")))).ToList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it using a HashSet:

```
Dim listaRows = ds.Tables(0).AsEnumerable(). _
                Cast(Of DataRow).ToList()

Dim valores = New HashSet(Of String) _
                          (listaRows.Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("FICHERO")))

Dim query = _
                listaFichero.Where(Function(l) _
                                       Not valores.Contains(l.FicheroParsed)).ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

What about comparing them as strings?

```
customClassCollection.SelectMany(x=>x.ParsedFileName).Except(dataRows.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("FieldName")));
```

Comment: If would be the other way, finding inside the customClassCollection what object are not in datatable.

Comment: Do you need vice versa?

Comment: I get this error: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.Data.DataRow,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Char]'.

Comment: you are using Except with a string. It uses char ienumerable

Comment: Is this ParsedFileName a char? Could you update the question with the class?

Answer (score 0):

I am not that sure weather i have fully understood your problem, but if you want to make collaboration among linq, data row and custom class you can do as follows:

At first make your datatable into IEnumearable. 
Actually LINQ queries works on data sources which implement the IEnumerable/ IQueryable Interface. But DataTable does not implement any of these. So we can not directly apply LINQ queries on a DataTable.

With the extension method of DataTable class called AsEnumerable returns an IEnumerable collection of DataRow. Use the AsEnumerable function on a DataTable and then play with some LINQ on the resulting collection.

```
List<CustomClass> cList= new List<CustomClass>();
if(dtTable.row.count>0){
cList=( from p in dtTable.AsEnumerable()
        select new CustomClass{
        propObj1= p.Field<OfType>("DatatableColumnName"),
        propObj2=p.FIeld<ofType>("DatabaseTableColumnName2")
}).ToList();
}
```

Hope this helps
Regards,
Rubel

Comment: The problem is that I need the customClass values that are not present in datatable. I managed to get it in the previous answer using hashset.